# sending a period to end a mail DATA telnet session in python

Tags: python, email, period, telnetlib

im using a telnetlib in python to connect to a simple mail server and send out an email; everything works fine until the very end after i enter the DATA command, you submit the body of your message and in order to submit the email in the server's queue, you need to type a period "." on a new line by itself so my end transaction snippet looks like so

```
self.tnet.write("\n.\n")
self.tnet.read_until("250")
```

where self.tnet is my telnet session var and read_until waits for the 250 Ok response saying the email has been sent to the queue of the email server and on its way for delivery; however, i do not get that 250 Ok response back and the connection times out to my 10sec timeout flag and no email is received in my inbox... any ideas? ive also tried

```
self.tnet.write(raw_input()+"\n")
```

and ive also tried grabbing the raw socket

```
self.sock=self.tnet.get_socket()
self.sock.send(".\n")
print self.sock.recv(1024)
```

no response... :/
ive also tried the return carriage "\r" in combination with "\n" and on it own to no avail

any ideas?

thank you,
~george

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need the `<CR><LF>` newline-squence try:

```
self.tnet.write("\r\n.\r\n")
```

hope that helps

Comment: sorry for the delayed response, i tried it out and that did the trick; thank you very much for the help!